# "All your team members _____ received"

Tags: grammar, questions

> I received feedback that some of the staff didn't receive the email below, so would you please ensure that all your team members **were received** the new plan for Ramadan.

Should it be *were received* or *are received* or anything else?

Comment: I'd rewrite your second sentence like this: *So, would you please ensure that all of your team members **receive** the new plan for Ramadan?*

Comment: Side note: May I suggest that you give a more descriptive title for future questions. Everything on this site is a "question", and most of them are about "grammar".

Comment: The text is clumsy and exact context unclear anyway, but surely the only specific grammatical point here that OP cares about is whether to use ***were*** or ***are**?* If we pragmatically assume he *intended* to specify Past Tense ***received***, the obvious "correction" is to use the proper auxiliary for Present Perfect:  *...please ensure all staff **have** received the email*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) As Michael Rybkin said,

All your team members receive the new plan for Ramadan

2) And I add another sentences

His proposal was warmly received.

Visitors are always received at the front door.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

> Due to feedback I received that some of the staff didn't receive the email below, please ensure that all your team members receive the new plan for Ramadan.

This is more grammatically correct.

If you want to restructure it to make it more effective, change the ordering to put the focus of it first and the reason after:

> Please ensure that all your team members receive the new plan for Ramadan.  I received feedback that not all members of staff received it the first time it was sent.

Comment: i will use the second one actually it looking more professional ,but i have a question; why we use two verbs respectively (was & sent)